# Arabic text with Polyglossia

Tags: polyglossia, arabic

I use Arabxetex and Polyglossia from Texlive 2013 on an OpenSuse 13.1 system to write Arabic. The Arabic text needs to be fully vocalized.

There are no Problems writing unvocalized Text, but adding a vocal sign breaks the connection between consonants: the words come out as a series of disjointed Arabic letters in their isolated letter form.

Has anyone else had similar problems? I don't know how to solve the problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 6):

Without a minimal example, I don’t know why you’re experiencing difficulties.  But with an up-to-date TeX Live, this example (adapted from the minimal example in the `arabxetex` documentation) works.  Perhaps the `voc` or `fullvoc` options are what you need?  If not, perhaps the font you’re using isn’t up to the task.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf]{arabxetex}% default options are "novoc" and "fdf2alif";
% other options are "voc", "fullvoc", "utf", "trans" and "fdf2noalif"
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
\begin{document}
\begin{arab}[voc]
وَهَذِهِ فِقرَةٌ بِالعَرَبِيَة مَعَ كَلِمَة اِنكلِيزِيَة (\textLR{English}).
\end{arab}

\bigskip

\begin{arab}[fullvoc]
وَهَذِهِ فِقرَةٌ بِالعَرَبِيَة مَعَ كَلِمَة اِنكلِيزِيَة (\textLR{English}).
\end{arab}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of the above code]

Comment: according to your experience, in which situations you would prefer `Polyglossia` over `Arabxetex`?

Comment: @doctorate My experience is limited: I have occasion to typeset Arabic just once or twice a year, which means that what worked the last time my be broken now, or vice versa, because this is a rapidly developing area.  I almost always work in `luatex` and turn to `xetex` only if something goes wrong.