# Font shape undefined(Font) problem with arabic text

Tags: arabic

Unfortunately I do not know arabic. I just have to copy paste some translated text into a latex document.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[LFE,LAE]{fontenc}
\usepackage[arabic]{babel}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Scheherazade}

\begin{document}
    هل سبق لك ولو لمرة واحدة في حياتك، أن تناولت 5 أكواب أو أكثر من المشروبات الكحولية (الجعة، النبيذ، الخمر) في آن واحد؟
\end{document}
```

`Font shape LAE/lmr/m/n' undefined(Font) using LAE/cmr/m/n' instead`

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! You could find some example here.

Comment: @Bobyandbob Thank you! Where exactly can I find an example?

Comment: e.g. [Typesetting a document using Arabic script](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12347/typesetting-a-document-using-arabic-script) or [Arabic text with Polyglossia](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159903/arabic-text-with-polyglossia) or just [tag `arabic`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arabic)